# Need assistance changing cell values in a google sheets script to match another cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api

I am new to scripts and have managed to piece together something functional from stuff cannibalized from scripts attached to tools that others have built. 
My current issue is I am using multiple scripts like the one below to change the formulas in multiple cells, but i am using Importranges for each to reference another tab in the current sheet. I think this messes up the performance pretty badly. Is there a script formula where I can just change the cell value (g15 in this case) to "=new assembly import!ap10" like you would put in a normal cell not in a script? I cant get the syntax right maybe? any help would be appreicated since right now i can only use formulas which seem innefficient.

```
spreadsheet.getRange('g15').activate();
spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=IMPORTRANGE("1raHB4DC5lkdreUiMe9GOpNFQRi4qIvEhLpzF4QpRYL4","new assembly import!ap10")'); //assembly errors
```

Comment: You need to quote sheet names that are not a single word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of your sheet should be inside single quotes. But because these have already been used to set the formula, you should use [escape characters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Syntax). So it should be like this:

```
spreadsheet.getRange('g15').setFormula('=IMPORTRANGE("1raHB4DC5lkdreUiMe9GOpNFQRi4qIvEhLpzF4QpRYL4","\'new assembly import\'!ap10")');
```

Please note that, as others said, you don't need to use [activate](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#activate) and [getCurrentCell](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getCurrentCell()) to modify a certain cell.

Also, if you don't want to use setFormula and you just want to change the value of a cell (`G15`) to the value of another cell (`AP10` in `new assembly import`), you can do the following instead (which, admittedly, is more efficient):

```
function withoutSetFormula() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var originSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("new assembly import");
  var destSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var originValue = originSheet.getRange("AP10").getValue();
  destSheet.getRange("G15").setValue(originValue);
}
```

The above sample does the following:

- It retrieves the origin and destination sheets (via [getSheetByName](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename)), called `new assembly import` and `Sheet1` respectively (please change this last one according to your preferences).
- It retrieves the value of cell `AP10` from the origin sheet (via [getRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation) and [getValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValue())).
- It sets the value of `G15` from the destination sheet (via [setValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue)).

Also please note that you could "import" several values to several cells if you specify the right origin and destination ranges. You don't need to use a script for each cell. Check [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)), [getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) and [setValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues).

I hope this is of any help.

Comment: Thanks! i will work with that and see what I can figure out.

Answer (score 0):

It's not required to use activate and getCurrentCell().  Instead try this:

```
spreadsheet.getRange('g15').setFormula('=IMPORTRANGE("1raHB4DC5lkdreUiMe9GOpNFQRi4qIvEhLpzF4QpRYL4","'new assembly import'!ap10")');
```

Note: the single quotes around the sheet name.